# Split a hash into duplicate hashes based on array data inside the hash Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

How can I create two or more new hashes from a single hash that has arrays fields as such:

```
{carStyle: "truck", make: ["Ford","Toyota"], model:["Ranger", "Tacoma"]}
```

so I would like two new hashes that come out to be like this:

```
{carStyle: "truck", make: "Ford", model: "Ranger"}
{carStyle: "truck", make: "Toyota", model: "Tacoma"}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to use map and collect to achieve this?  Or if someone has seen a similar question that they could point me to that i might have missed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: will `carStyle` always only have one value, while `make` and `model` have the same number and in corresponding order so the first make goes with the first model, etc?

Comment: yes to both questions

Comment: When giving an example, it is helpful to assign all input objects to variables (for example, `h = {carStyle:...}`). That way, references can be made to those variables in comments and answers without the need to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {carStyle: "truck", make: ["Ford","Toyota"], model:["Ranger", "Tacoma"]}
data[:make].zip(data[:model]).map{|x|
  { carStyle: data[:carStyle], make: x[0], model: x[1] }
}
```

Mark Reed suggested even better solution:

```
data[:make].zip(data[:model]).map{|x,y|
  { carStyle: data[:carStyle], make: x, model: y }
}
```

Comment: I like it.  You could also do  ...`map{ |x,y| { ... make: x, model: y }}` and avoid the indexing.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkReed, I'll add your answer too

Comment: Thank you both! This works perfectly and gets me headed in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {carStyle: "truck", make: ["Ford","Toyota"], model: ["Ranger", "Tacoma"]}

style, makes, models = h.values_at(:carStyle, :make, :model)
  # => ["truck", ["Ford", "Toyota"], ["Ranger", "Tacoma"]] 

makes.zip(models).map {|make, model| {carStyle: style, make: make, model: model}}
  #=> [{:carStyle=>"truck", :make=>"Ford",   :model=>"Ranger"},
  #    {:carStyle=>"truck", :make=>"Toyota", :model=>"Tacoma"}]
```

I've added the local variables to improve readability.

Comment: 1 extra line of code for the increased readability is well worth it.